# lodash sortBy is not returning result as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

Here I am trying to sort this array by both attributes age and user. The first sort by age then the user. Where age is the same then sort by the user attribute.

```
var users = [
      { 'user': 'kurt',   'age': 1 },
      { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 11 },
      { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 3 },
      { 'user': 'alex', 'age': 7 },
      { 'user': 'box', 'age': 7 },
      { 'user': 'foo', 'age': 7 }
    ];

_.sortBy(users, (o) => [o.age, o.user]);
```

Output:

```
[
 { 'user': 'kurt', 'age': 1 },
 { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 11 },
 { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 3 },
 { 'user': 'alex', 'age': 7 },
 { 'user': 'box', 'age': 7 },
 { 'user': 'foo', 'age': 7 }
]
```

Here we can see **age: 11** should come at the last but it is coming after **age: 1**. Am I missing something here? or it is a bug in lodash sortBy function? Expected output as follows:

Expected output:

```
[
 { 'user': 'kurt', 'age': 1 },
 { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 3 },
 { 'user': 'alex', 'age': 7 },
 { 'user': 'box', 'age': 7 },
 { 'user': 'foo', 'age': 7 },
 { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 11 }
]
```

Comment: No, age passed as an integer. I am trying to sort this array first age attribute then the user attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
var sorted = _.sortBy(users, (o) => o.age, (o) => o.user);
// or
var sorted = _.sortBy(users, [(o) => o.age, (o) => o.user]);
```

Comment: Here I am trying to sort this array by both attributes age and user. The first sort by age then the user. Where age is the same then sort by the user attribute.

Comment: @KrishanKantSharma This is what the code I've posted does. And keep in mind, `_.sortBy()` **returns** the sorted array, it doesn't sort the existing one.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to specify a second key, you can just provide the age property:
`_.sortBy(users, 'age');`

For the expected output using both properties you should use:

`_.sortBy(users,['age','user']);`

But your example data is not very good to see how it sorts based on the user prop, try to sufle it a bit to see how the user property helps sorting by user:

```
var users = [
      { 'user': 'foo', 'age': 7 }
      { 'user': 'kurt',   'age': 1 },
      { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 11 },
      { 'user': 'box', 'age': 7 }, 
      { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 3 },
      { 'user': 'alex', 'age': 7 },
    ];

    _.sortBy(users, 'age','user');
```

Comment: I am trying to sort this array by both attributes age and user. The first sort by age then the user. Where age is the same then sort by the user attribute.

Comment: @KrishanKantSharma I just updated my answer to better reflect that

Answer (score 1):

You could use it like this:

`_.orderBy(users, ["age", "user"])`